# Mysterious Unexplained Appearance of Feature Films (live-action or animated) -- Who will notice? Who will care?

Tags: secret-society, conspiracy

In the modern age, it doesn't take much (cheap commodity cameras, plus actors) to make a film, and quite a bit of animation can be done by a single shut-in with a computer.

But to make something like a Hollywood-tier feature film with special effects and location shots requires *quite a bit of resources and a good number of people*. Likewise, to create animation at the level of Pixar or the better class of Japanese anime studios, requires many, many man-hours of work, which can only done by a good number of people working full time, some of whom will be experts.

The point is, nobody can make one of these works of art/media without involving a large effort, a great many people, and *money.*

Suppose that Some Guy starts posting never-before-seen, unexplained, mysterious feature films on Youtube? Who is going to notice, care, or investigate? Will the government get involved/try to identify him even if he's not actually making any taxable money from this?

Comment: [They noticed nyancat, no?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QH2-TGUlwu4). If they noticed [the badger, the mushroom and the snake, don't forget the snake](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EIyixC9NsLI), I reckon they'll notice a feature film too.

Comment: This looks like an open ended question. You are not giving any metric to evaluate the answers.

Comment: I thought that the entire point of posting something on YT was to be noticed by millions of people... And what is the meaning of the word "investigate"? Do you mean, officially investigate? Nobody, unless Some Guy fails to pay their taxes of the revenue derived from the millions and millions of YT views.

Comment: Is it in some way encroaching on a taboo subject perhaps.... Maybe goat porn or a government conspiracy involving a protected minority or perhaps a *real* alien autopsy or a celebrity scandal or necrophillia, maybe (or several of these combined)? Otherwise meh.

Comment: *shut-in with a computer* Perhaps an ill-chosen expression given that being socially responsible in the times of Covid-19d is in fact all about being shut in with a computer.

Comment: Just FYI, William Gibson was there first with Pattern Recognition.

Comment: What if this unknown shut-in created a leap in combining computer animation and AI, such that one person could be that productive. Perhaps inventing a new language to describe animation to the computer. I dreamed of such a language when I was younger, but I've never developed the AI background to create it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**People in the business would notice, for sure.**

Nearly everyone watches films for entertainment.  But professionals also watch because it is their business.  A talent scout or agent notes an actress and wonders "Why have I never seen her?  Who is she?"  He realizes the film has no credits and then he is really interested.  He calls his friends and they all check it out.  None of them have ever seen any of these actors or actresses before.  One of them turns up two other videos, with some of the same actors.  These do not have credits either.

A location scout is interested in the site where some scenes were shot.  She wants to know where it is.  She realizes that the film has no credits, and seems to have fallen out of the sky.  It is a high quality film.  In one scene there is a beer can visible in the distance.  On zooming in the label says Roanoake.  There has never been a beer brewed named Roanoake.  Her friend points out that some of the cars must have been custom made because he does not recognize the make or model.

A speech accent analyst weighs in.  He thinks that the actors are South African but there are some real differences he cannot place.  His video is artfully made.

People become passionate about understanding the movies.  They research them in depth, like the [Second Time Around](https://tonedeaf.thebrag.com/the-30-year-puzzle-of-the-mystery-song-finally-solved/) mystery German pop song from the 1980s.  But as opposed to the song, careful analysis turns up some truly disconcerting aspects of these movies.

This would make a fine SCP.  http://www.scp-wiki.net

Comment: It would indeed make a very fine SCP entry.

Answer (score 7):

## The Government Will Care

As another answer has stated, people in the moviemaking business will definitely notice.  Nobody will know anybody who worked on any of these films.  For professional reasons, they will want to figure out what the deal is.

So the mystery will definitely draw peoples' attention.  And there's a simple reason that - once people realize how strange this is - the government will care enough to try and unravel the mystery: Taxes and permits.

Creating a feature film involves moving gobs and gobs of money around.  Throwing around that kind of money carries significant tax implications.  The government is eventually going to realize nobody's even filed any paperwork.

How can what appears to be a movie that must have been shot on location in (say) Chicago have *no record* of permits being issued to film in public?  How could a shoot have gone on there for what - our industry sources say - must have been at least six weeks, without paying anything to the city at all?  Who are all these people, and why have none of the actors (whoever they are) involved with the production of this film (or any of the others) ever paid taxes on their pay?  Why can't we find any evidence of any corporation having signed all the contracts that you need (with insurers, the screen actor's guild, etc) to do a job on that scale?

Whatever's going on, it basically has to involve some *very* sophisticated new kind of money laundering.  Or at least, that's what they'll think at first.  And that will definitely be enough to convince them to open an investigation.

Answer (score 4):

### No one will care, unless he gets an audience

So people post feature length films to youtube. People post strange mysterious videos to youtube. Top tier you tubers are already use Hollywood style production equipment. Shows like RWBY exist. No one cares.

Youtube posts over 300 hours of content every minute, so even with a quality production, getting noticed is difficult. This will be especially true for anyone posting feature length films, which can't be uploaded at the same frequency.

If they manage to become popular, then they will certainly be investigated by their fans and imitators, regardless of the technical quality of said films.

Answer (score 2):

There are such things as fan-films. Look at the quality of production of movies like Kung Fury - it's not the Marvel Cinematic Universe quality (despite starring Zardu Hasseulfrau), but except for plot it matches well the quality of many movies of the past two decades.

As time passes, it becomes easier to make such things. Also notice that you mentioned animation. When Gorillaz came out, the marketing of the band was this whole "who are these guys?", and their videos were top notch animation.

Finally, there are lots of top notch animations that are famous made by rather unknown studios (try searching for "Fallen Art" in Youtube). All it would take for thede things to go from short clips to full length movies would be money.

So yes, people might be led to believe that a new blockbuster is an crowd-funded indie production.

And if you didn't care about quality, I would remind you of *Blair Witch*. That was a cheap one that got really famous.

Comment: A worthwhile consideration, but part of the assumption here is that it's something that people *know* can't be produced by an individual or very small team with a low budget.

Comment: @ikrase the budgets for the works I mentioned were relatively small, so were the teams.

Answer (score 0):

Very hard to imagine that anyone would notice, or care, unless the video post gained some kind of cult following… Which is of course extremely unlikely. You can’t create a hit movie just by posting it online.

Only a handful of people would ever see the movie, as has been noted there is a vast quantity of content on YouTube. All those who did see it it is highly unlikely that anyone would be particularly curious about how it was made-when was the last time you wondered something like that?

Comment: "You can’t create a hit movie just by posting it online." You can if the quality is there. I'm pretty sure if someone posted a movie online that had Hollywood-level production quality *and* was a good movie in other respects (something which can't be said of everything that comes out of Hollywood), people would notice. OTOH, if it's tripe, then yes, just having quality special effects doesn't guarantee anything.

Comment: (Also the possibility that they might promote it a bit with (equally mysterious) social media.) Even if it wasn't something having really wide appeal, it probably would get noticed by *some* people who would take interest, and spread around a bit.